# Concatenate to multiple strings (Perl)

Tags: arrays, string, perl

Is there an easy way to concatenate a single value to the end of a list of strings?

I have...

```
($string1,$string2) .= (',',','); #A comma for each string and one to separate them.
```

But it doesn't add anything.

I'd also like to concatenate the values from an array, but also don't get anything added to my strings...

```
($string1,$string2) .= @array_to_add;
```

And

```
($string1,$string2) .= (@array_to_add);
```

Neither works...

Comment: Am I understanding it right, that you want to take a single string and add it to the end of mulitple target strings?

Comment: For the first part, yes. I want a comma after each of the strings in the list. For the second, I need the values from one list added to another. For example if @array_to_add has 2 strings ('a','b') and $string1='c' and $string2='d', I want for the result to be $string1='ca' and $string2='db'.

Comment: I don't think that any of those things are possible. Not to my knowledge, at least, Would have to be done seperately. But I would love to be proven wrong.

Answer (score 1):

```
$string1 .= $to_append[0];
$string2 .= $to_append[1];
```

If you had two arrays:

```
$strings[$_] .= $to_append[$_] for 0..$#strings;
```

As a function:

```
sub append_one_to_each {
   my $to_append = shift;
   return map { $_[$_] . $to_append->[$_] } 0..$#_;
}

say for append_one_to_each(\@to_append, $string1, $string2); 
  -or-
say for append_one_to_each(\@to_append, @strings);
```